Lifting a mod-n class to an integral class and generalized Stiefel-Whitney classes
Suppose $M$ is a smooth, compact, oriented Riemannian 4-manifold, and let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $2$.
Does the obstruction to lifting a class $x \in H^2(M, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ to an integral class in $H^{2}(M, \mathbb{Z})$ vanish for $n \neq 2$?
The short exact sequence of coefficients,
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\times n} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\rho_{n}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$$
where $\rho_n$ is reduction modulo $n$, induces a long-exact sequence in cohomology for which the Bockstein map at degree $2$ is
$$\mathsf{Bock}: H^{2}(M, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{3}(M, \mathbb{Z})$$
For $n=2$, there is a well-known proof that $\mathsf{Bock}(w_2)$ is trivial. (See for example, ref [1] below, for a proof.) The proof relies on the existence of a characteristic element.
For $n > 2$, it is clear that if the manifold is simply connected, $H^3(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is trivial, and hence so is the Bockstein map.
Question 1: Is the analogous result true for $n > 2$ when no addtional assumption on $M$ is made? If not, is there a counterexample? I can imagine obstructions when there is torsion in the cohomology.
Question 2: Is there a reference for discussions of such mod-$n$ versions of Stiefel-Whitney classes?
[1] https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Math/ewExternalFiles/spin.pdf
